# Do German resident who is Nigerian still have to obtain a visa to travel to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, nigerian-citizens, german-residents

I am a Nigerian citizen having residence permit and living in Germany. Do I still need a visa to travel to the united kingdom for the purpose of visiting

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Having a German residence permit makes no difference https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/nigeria/tourism/no